# How to create doubly linked list in haskell?

Tags: haskell

How do you create a doubly linked list in Haskell? I am trying to familiarize myself with the Haskell language and am trying to create this data structure using Haskell's functional paradigm.

Comment: If it is indeed possible

Comment: if it can be done

Comment: Note that the linked duplicate assumes you want a cyclic list, and that you can't have an empty list.